# Show a Category Specific Info Box

Tags: posts, php, categories, customization

I have a number of categories which are regions of the country (north, south, etc).

I would like to display some kind of info box at the end of each post which falls into one of these categories with an icons and links specific to that category, such as MAPS, HISTORY.

Each region category would have the same link names and icons, but each would direct to a different URL relevant to that category.

For instance

NORTH
Maps - maps.com/north
History - history.com/north

SOUTH
Maps - maps.com/south
History - history.com/south

Thought about creating a widget area, but it could become messy. Any better ideas?!?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to print content on the front end. The "best" way depends on the details of the project and your description is very superficial.

The option I can think of are:

1. Just edit the appropriate theme template to use [`has_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category)
   to display your links to the category URLs
2. Do the same as above but use a filter on `the_content` to avoid
   editing the template files. Good if you may use multiple themes, not
   just one, or if this needs to be portable to other sites.
3. Use a widget. This can be a bit trickier but I don't know about
   "messy".

Which is "best"? Or better than a widget? No idea. That depends on what you need to do, where you need to place the content, etc.